# Flexslider stops working when browser window is off focus

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I'm using FlexSlider-2.6.3

It's working the way I want it to work so far, but here is what happens.
The flexslider element is working normally when I click on the page. It starts rotating, doing its usual carousel characteristics.

I have links on my page that create popups to different windows. When those popups appear, obviously the focus shifts away from the page that contains the flexslider element.

When the popups appear, or if I shift focus away from the page with the Flexslider element, the carousel effect stops working. It just stays on one image, until I click on the page. After I click on that page, the element begins functioning.

Any way that I can have the flexslider element continue to work, regardless of page focus?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [this answer](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/issues/1633). I tried this fix in my own example and it worked for me.

In the file jquery.flexslider.js around line 1088-1092, there is a section of code that checks the window's focus and toggles the *focused* variable accordingly.

```
$( window ).blur( function ( e ) {
  focused = false;
}).focus( function ( e ) {
  focused = true;
});
```

Around line 808 of that same file, the script checks the status of the *focused* variable in order to decide if it should continue the carousel effect.

```
slider.animateSlides = function() {
  if (!slider.animating && focused ) { slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next")); }
};
```

A quick fix would be to comment out lines 1088-1092, which makes the *focused* variable always true.

If you are using the minified version (jquery.flexslider-min.js), then you will need to replace that with the file mentioned above.